# How to get the ClientRectangle of Form or Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I can able to get the window/form  as image using GetWindowRect of User32.dll and window handle value. But i don't need to get the whole window/form, only i need to get the client rectangle of window/form to save it as an image.

Please anyone suggest me any ideas to achieve this?

```
private class User32
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

}

 User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
 User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
```

Please look the below image and i need to create the image for highlighted(red) area.

[image]

Comment: GetWindowRect() returns the entire window, including caption and border.  GetClientRect() returns what you want.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, I tried your suggestion, but TOP and LEFT postion are get as "0". So still i got whole window.

How to solve this? Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: It is in client coordinates, use MapWindowPoints() to translate to screen coordinates.